# How can I create a canvas, then set its color, and then append it to a div using Javascript/ Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I am trying to build a basic game and somehow got really hung up on the first few steps. I am trying to create a canvas, the the color of the canvas, and then append to a div element. Every time I load this I either get an error, or nothing. Even if the 2 console.logs load properly. Please help!
My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dodge</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/journal/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-fHWoqb8bPKjLiC7AuV6qy/lt0hrzfwM0ciyAu7Haf5w= sha512-3t2GeiCRNeKhZnUaUMygGiLKZzb/vPhvfw3y1Rt2FCwKuRaLVrOCTpavIYsZ4xqM52mbO7M93NaXbm/9dOA2Og==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="../../../game.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
    <h1 id="h1">Dodge the enemy by pressing the left and right arrow keys!</h1>
        <button
        id="play"
        class="btn btn-primary">Play game!</button>
        </br>
        </br>
        <button
        id="again"
        class="btn btn-primary">Play Again!</button>
        <div id="play-area">
        </div>
  </center>
</body>
</html>`
```

And heres the JS:

```
$(function () {
function createCanvas(width, height, id) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var id2 = "#" + id;
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    canvas.id = id;
    $(id2).css("color", "lawngreen");
    $("#game-area").append(canvas);
}


$("#play").click(function () {
    console.log("hello");
    createCanvas(900, 900, "game-canvas");
    console.log("hi!");
  });
});
```

Comment: `game-area` only appears once in the code you've posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you create the canvas object correctly, but you should also append it to the body. This is done after basic parameters are set.
After that you can manipulate the css with jQuery.
It works in my fiddle.

Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/xu15q5h8/

I changed your code to point out how it correctly works:

```
$(function () {

 function createCanvas(width, height, id) {

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

  canvas.id = id;
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  body.appendChild(canvas);
  $('canvas').css('background-color', 'rgba(158, 167, 184, 0.2)');   
  cursorLayer = document.getElementById("CursorLayer");
  console.log(cursorLayer);

}

$("#play").click(function () {
  console.log("hello");
  createCanvas(900, 900, "game-canvas");
  alert("hi!");
  });
});
```

Comment: Or append it to another element, like your game-arena ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just draw the color onto the canvas instead of using CSS.

```
function createCanvas(width, height, id) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var id2 = "#" + id;
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    canvas.id = id;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "lawngreen";
    ctx.fillRect (0, 0, width, height);
    $("#play-area").append(canvas);
}
```

**[Here is the modified code demo.](http://jsbin.com/guyijat/1/edit?html,css,js,output)**